# Tkinter AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'canvas' and matplotlib graphs don't update until I resize the tkinter window

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, tkinter-canvas, axes

Matplotlib graph on tkinter canvas gives error - 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'canvas'

```
# Create window
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.resizable()
window.state('zoomed')


# Create Title
window.title('Title')


# adding frame of buttons
BFrame = tkinter.Frame(window)
BFrame.pack(side=tkinter.TOP)    

# This defines the Python GUI backend to use for matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

# Initialize matplotlib figure for graphing purposes
fig = Figure(figsize=(5,3), dpi = 100)

global sbpt_1, sbpt_2, sbpt_3

sbpt_1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)
sbpt_2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
sbpt_3 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3)


#Rotating x-ticks
sbpt_1.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
sbpt_2.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
sbpt_3.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)


#Subplot Titles
sbpt_1.title.set_text('Title A \n')
sbpt_2.title.set_text('Title B \n')
sbpt_3.title.set_text('Title C \n')
fig.suptitle('VISUALIZE FILES')


# Tight layout often produces nice results
# but requires the title to be spaced accordingly
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.82)


# Special type of "canvas" to allow for matplotlib graphing
display = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)
display.draw()
display.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

#Navigator
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(display, window)
toolbar.update()
display._tkcanvas.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

.................

def plot_utm():
    content.plot (color = '#3BB9FF', ax = sbpt_1)
    sbpt_1.canvas.draw()
    
def plot_tm():
    shp_TM.plot(color = '#4CC417', ax = sbpt_2)
    sbpt_2.canvas.draw()
    
def plot_om():  
    shp_TMOM.plot(color = '#FFA62F', ax = sbpt_3)
    sbpt_3.canvas.draw()

.........

# To make the window running
window.mainloop()
```

This error comes up.:
[image: This error comes up.]

Plot on Tkinter Canvas even after clicking on visualize button:
[image: Plot on Tkinter Canvas even after clicking on visualize button]

There is a problem in these lines of the full code.
If I run this code, it gives an error - 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'canvas'
and after clicking on visualize button, plots do not appear on the canvas but if I resize the window using minimize/maximize button, the plots will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by updating the functions

```
def plot_utm():
    sbpt_1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1) 
    content.plot (color = '#3BB9FF', ax = sbpt_1)
    display.draw_idle()
    
def plot_tm():
    sbpt_2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
    shp_TM.plot(color = '#4CC417', ax = sbpt_2)
    display.draw_idle()
    
def plot_om():
    sbpt_3 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3)
    shp_TMOM.plot(color = '#FFA62F', ax = sbpt_3)
    display.draw_idle()
```